# html tags inside a goJS node

Tags: javascript, angular, gojs

I'm trying to add an HTML tag or design inside a goJS treemap node, but its not getting added.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the node template by adding a **TextBlock**.  Your probably want to clip the text if it's too big for the node, so perhaps this modification of the TreeMap extension sample:

```
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, { fill: "rgba(99,99,99,0.2)", strokeWidth: 0 },
          new go.Binding("fill")),
        $(go.TextBlock, { alignment: go.Spot.TopLeft },
          new go.Binding("text", "", tooltipString).ofObject()),
        {
          toolTip: $("ToolTip",
            $(go.TextBlock, new go.Binding("text", "", tooltipString).ofObject())
          )
        }
      );
```